# Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified. Mobile Dependency Resolver in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle, gradlew

OS:
Windows 11 [Latest Stable Build]

Problem:
I think the problem is with gradle and it is providing gradlew file but not gradlew.bat file I don't know why maybe I have WSL installed, or maybe I have few tools that replicate UNIX commands.

Error:

```
Win32Exception: ApplicationName='D:\CodingHub\Unity\TEST\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\gradlew.bat', CommandLine='--daemon -b "D:\CodingHub\Unity\TEST\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle" "-PANDROID_HOME=C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.47f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\SDK" "-PTARGET_DIR=D:\CodingHub\Unity\TEST\Assets\Plugins\Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=https://android-sdk.is.com/;https://maven.google.com/" "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:7.2.5;com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0;com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.2.1" "-PUSE_JETIFIER=1" "-PDATA_BINDING_VERSION=4.0.1"', CurrentDirectory='D:\CodingHub\Unity\TEST\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle', Native error= The system cannot find the file specified.
    
System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) (at <1e13855442cf491a8b11d7de866cc016>:0)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () (at <1e13855442cf491a8b11d7de866cc016>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
GooglePlayServices.CommandLine.RunViaShell (System.String toolPath, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] envVars, GooglePlayServices.CommandLine+IOHandler ioHandler, System.Boolean useShellExecution, System.Boolean stdoutRedirectionInShellMode, System.Boolean setLangInShellMode) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/git/unity-jar-resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/CommandLine.cs:638)
GooglePlayServices.CommandLine.Run (System.String toolPath, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] envVars, GooglePlayServices.CommandLine+IOHandler ioHandler) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/git/unity-jar-resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/CommandLine.cs:510)
GooglePlayServices.CommandLine+<RunAsync>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/git/unity-jar-resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/CommandLine.cs:135)
System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (System.Object state) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
UnityEngine.<>c:<RegisterUECatcher>b__0_0(Object, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)`
```

Unity Editors:
I have tried multiple Unity Editors as I thought this was just a specific version issue but the problem persists in every single one of them.

- 2021.3.24f1
- 2020.3.47f1
- 2022.2.18f1

Debug:
I have tried using custom SDKs and NDKs for all the version and even using custom JDK and nothing is solved plus I tried using gradle installed using scoop but that also gave the same error. I have reinstalled and removed, literally did everything but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

As I though the problem was I have installed mingw and msys2 with scoop and they were in the path environment due to scoop shims and that is why the gradle was treating the OS as linux so after removing them it build successfully.